# Hash tables (dispersion) representation on paper

Tags: c

Let's say that I have a function, `h(x)=[½(x mod 8)]`. When I draw the hash table (dispersion), will the indexes will be from 0->7 or 0->3. (The `[]` means it only takes the integer part.)

I'm expecting it to be 0->3, but some of my classmates say it's 0->7.

Answer (score 4):

First, x mod 8 (`x % 8` in C) is always between 0 and 7 inclusive. Now multiplying this with 1/2 will give you 0 to 3 and "0==>3" is the right answer.

Comment: So table is 0->3. Thank you so much.